# come back when I select an item from the list

Tags: android, android-layout, listadapter

I made a list such that every time I click on an item, it opens another page. The problem is that if you use the back button, it will close the application. I would rather return to the previous menu instead; how can I fix this?

```
public class Listview extends Activity {

    static ListView listView;

    static public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Person, Void> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            // Prima di iniziare a inserire gli elementi svuotiamo l'adapter
            ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).clear();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground ( Void... params ) {
            Person[] people = { new Person( "Privacy",R.drawable.icon1 ) };
            Person[] people1 = {new Person( "Visualizzazione", R.drawable.icon1 )};
            Person[] people2=  { new Person( "Notifiche", R.drawable.icon1)};

            // riempimento casuale della lista delle persone
            Random r = new Random();

            for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
                // Pubblichiamo il progresso
                publishProgress( people);
                publishProgress( people1);
                publishProgress( people2);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate ( Person... values ) {
            // Aggiungiamo il progresso pubblicato all'adapter
            ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).add( values[0] );
            super.onProgressUpdate( values );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );
        listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.personListView );
        listView.setAdapter( new PersonAdapter( this, R.layout.row_item, new ArrayList<Person>() ) );
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Person p = (Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        onCreate1(savedInstanceState);
                        //  setContentView(R.layout.main1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
                }
            }
        });
        new BackgroundWorker().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        onCreate1(savedInstanceState);
        //  setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        break;
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
}
```

You should not use `setContentView` more than once in an `Activity`. You should instead be launching a new `Activity` with `startActivity()`. This way you have a history of Activities that will be returned through upon pressing Back.

Answer (score 2):

You override the back button and implement your own code. Like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Your code
    return;
    }
```